# Create Grid Where Every Other (String) Element is Empty

Tags: javascript, string

A grid of size 3 should look like:

```
# #
 # 
# #
```

A grid of size 4 should look like:

```
# # 
 # #
# # 
 # #
```

A grid of size 5 should look like:

```
# # #
 # # 
# # #
 # #
# # #
```

etc.

Usually, to create a "normal" grid, I'd do something like:

```js
function makeGrid (input) {
  let grid = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
      grid += "#".repeat(input) + "\n";
    }
  return grid;
}

console.log(makeGrid(3));
```

But in this case, I'm having trouble making sure that the *rows* are created with the correct *starting element* - either `#` or  .

My attempt:

```js
function makeSpecialGrid (input) {

  let specialGrid = "";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    let row = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (j % 2 === 0) {
        row += "#";
      } 
      row += " ";
    }
    specialGrid += row;
  }

  return specialGrid;
  
}

console.log(makeSpecialGrid(3));
```

Which, of course, only creates one row.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function grid(n) {
  let result = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      result += " #".repeat(Math.ceil(n / 2)).slice(1);
    else
      result += " #".repeat(Math.floor(n / 2)) + " ";
    result += "\n";
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(grid(5));
console.log(grid(3));
console.log(grid(11));
```

Comment: So the fact that you have `result += "\n";` _after_ the if and the else is what causes the grid to form new lines when `i === n` - okay.

Comment: @HappyHands31 Not quite -- in my code, `i` represents the row number, so when `i === n`, the loop terminates.

Comment: Ah okay. That makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
function gridGenerator (size) {
  let grid = "";
  // i is the lines
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // j is the characters
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
        grid += '#';
      } else {
        grid += ' ';
      }
    }
    grid += '\n';
  }
  return grid;
}
```